# Unable to acess Active Directory when app is deployed in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I've an application (ASP.Net v4.0) which is on a win7 system. I'm able to connect to an Active Directory (in a server) in both ways, like debugging from Visual Studio 2013 or like deploying in local IIS. But when I publish the same code in Server's IIS, its not connecting to the Active Directory.

Error:

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007052E): The user name or password is incorrect.\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)\u000d\u000a   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()\u000d\u000a   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()\u000d\u000a   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)\u000d\u000a   at tap.dom.usr.Authentication.ConnectAcitveDirectory(String groupName, String domainName, String serverName, String adminUserName, String queryUserName, String queryPassword)

Any authentication issues? Im a newbie on this part. Please help me. The below is the code:

```
DirectoryEntry connectionAD = new DirectoryEntry(_serverProtocol + serverName, domainName + "\\" + queryUserName, queryPassword);
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(connectionAD);
search.PageSize = 1001;
search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=" + adminUserName + "))";
SearchResultCollection result = search.FindAll();
if (result.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (SearchResult item in result)
    {
        if (item.Properties["SAMAccountName"].Count > 0
                && Convert.ToString(item.Properties["distinguishedName"][0]).Contains("OU=" + groupName))
            return "Active Directory is all set up! User was authenticated~0";
    }
}
```

What could be the reasons for the error?

Comment: More information: Server: windows Server 2012 R2.  IIS version: 8.5.9600.16384.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have impersonation configured in your web.config file?

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

> This causes ASP.NET to impersonate the account that is configured as
>   the anonymous account from Microsoft Internet Information Services
>   (IIS). As a result of this configuration, all requests to this
>   application run under the security context of the configured account.
>   The user provides credentials to authenticate against the Active
>   Directory, but the account that accesses the Active Directory is the
>   configured account.

You can read more in the Microsoft support article: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326340

Comment: Hi Cristina, 
I've changed the ASP.Net Impersonation to true, and it threw 500 internal Server Error. Then, I've added a specific user that I've been using to query the ldap as Identity to Impersonate. It is still giving the same error.

Comment: Try to follow all the steps in the article, to see maybe you missed some configuration of IIS.

Comment: Whatever the things specified, I've done as it is. Infact, some of the IIS settings provided are for earlier version of IIS.

Comment: I've created a console app and copied that exe into server system and executed it. It threw the same error. Looks like not an issue with IIS, Something related to the code

Comment: The error is: _The user name or password is incorrect_. I think it's something related to the user name. Do you specify the right domain name?

Comment: Yes, without that, I can even login to AD. As I've specified earlier in my psot, the code works fine. Im able to connect to AD, get the Users and do all the related stuff. But when I move this web application or console application into the server (where AD server also installed), its not working. Hope I made it clear to you.